# zf2 ServiceManager vs ServiceLocator

Tags: zend-framework2, service-locator, servicemanager

I am learning zf2, reading docs, tutorials etc from the web. Now I am confused regarding `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManagerAwareInterface.php` and `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface.php`.

Also in some place (like controller) I use `$this->getServiceLocator()` to fetch the `ServiceManager` object while at some other places we use `->getServiceManager()` and it also returns the same `ServiceManager` object.

Comment: @Sam, Why do we need both methods then?

Comment: But why are there two interfaces. `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManagerAwareInterface.php` and `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface.php`. If SM is the implementaion of SL, why do we have a separate interface.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Locator is the interface. The design of Zend Framework 2 is done with "design by contract" which means you rely on interfaces rather than classes. The Manager is a default implementation of the Locator.

All but one component use the Locator. However, the manager provides more features than the interface says. The `Zend\Mvc\Application` uses these features and therefore relies on the Manager instead of the Locator.

The decision to use the Locator in the *Aware initializers was made too late for the release, so this is why there is both a `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` and a `ServiceManagerAwareInterface`. There was already userland code using the Manager's initializer so it's kept for backwards compatibility. Internally all components use the Locator initialzer. If you have to choose, pick the Locator and leave the Manager as much as possible aside.

Quite some time ago I also blogged about the Locator and the Manager: https://juriansluiman.nl/article/120/using-zend-framework-service-managers-in-your-application

Answer (score 5):

The `ServiceManager` is basically the implementation of the `ServiceLocator` interface. The reason of having the two is that a user can have their own implementation of the `ServiceLocator` interface. When you request the `->getServiceManager()` it returns you the explicit `ServiceManager` implementation. By using `->getServiceLocator()` you are requesting any implementation of the `ServiceLocator` interface which can be the implementation by the `ServiceManager` or your own. But as most of the times there is only the default `ServiceManager` implelmentation so you will get the same object.

Comment: that makes some sense but again why do we have `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManagerAwareInterface.php`. and which approach do you think should be used.

Comment: i stick with the `ServiceLocator` as it also has a trait available, so I just use the trait and don't have to implement the SL/SM on my own over and over.